# persist the data even after reboot freebsd server

Tags: freebsd, iso

im creating iso using freebsd src code. but boot process is happening through RAM. if i reboot the server no custom data is available. ive created mount points but after reboot data is no more. need to boot from hard disk and data should persist.

Comment: Install FreeBSD on the hard disk?

Comment: Or `NomadBSD is a persistent live system for USB flash drives, based on FreeBSD. ` https://www.freebsd.org/where.html

Comment: on reboot image again booting. we need to persist the data. when we create mount points after reboot all mounts are being removed(we are using zfs).